# How to enrich UIImage data with metadata

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, phasset

In my app I'm trying to have image data have metadata (location, timestamp etc.). I'm using UIImagePickerController to do image capture, and the delegate function of which has:

```
info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage]
info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.phAsset] 
info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaMetadata]
```

So for the images picked from the library `.phAsset` has everything I need. I just use `.getDataFromPHAsset` function to get the enriched data. However, for the images that were just taken `.phAsset` is nil. I thought about trying to somehow combine  `.originalImage` and `.mediaMetadata` together into single Data object, but can't get the result desired. I tried to use this approach: https://gist.github.com/kwylez/a4b6ec261e52970e1fa5dd4ccfe8898f

I know I can also make custom imageCapture controller, using `AVCaptureSession`, and use `AVCapturePhoto` function `.fileDataRepresentation()` on `didFinishProcessingPhoto` delegate call, but that's not my first choice.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure mediaMetadata will not have location info. Use this [CLLocation extension.](https://gist.github.com/nitrag/343fe13f01bb0ef3692f2ae2dfe33e86)

Then use the function below to add the metadata to the image data:

```
func addImageProperties(imageData: Data, properties: NSMutableDictionary) -> Data? {
  let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
  dict[(kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary as String)] = properties

  if let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, nil) {
    if let uti = CGImageSourceGetType(source) {
      let destinationData = NSMutableData()
      if let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(destinationData, uti, 1, nil) {
        CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destination, source, 0, dict as CFDictionary)
        if CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination) == false {
          return nil
        }                    
        return destinationData as Data
      }
    }
  }
  return nil
}
```

Usage:

```
if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0), let metadata = locationManager.location?.exifMetadata() {
  if let newImageData = addImageProperties(imageData: imageData, properties: metadata) {
    // newImageData now contains exif metadata
  }
}
```